# How do i return an object at a time, from an array and make a button active by default

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, mapping

```
    function LoginLib() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState('')

    const tabs = [
        {
            id:"tab1", 
            name: "Live Sports", 
            subHeadline: "Catch your games at home or on the go. Stream live games from major college and pro leagues including the NCAA®, NBA, NHL, NFL, and more.", 
            text: "Live TV plan required. Regional restrictions, blackouts and additional terms apply.",
            link: "See Detials",
            bckgrd: "loginLib__sportsNews"
        },

        {
            id:"tab2", 
            name: "Breaking News",  
            subHeadline: "Keep pace with what's going on locally and globally with trusted opinions from all the top news networks.",  
            text: "Live TV plan required. Regional restrictions, blackouts and additional terms apply.",
            link: "See Detials",
            bckgrd: "loginLib__breakingNews"
        },
        {
            id: "tab3", 
            name: "Biggest Events", 
            subHeadline: "Spectacular, can't-miss moments like the Olympics, Grammys®, Oscars®, Emmys®, and more.", 
            text: "Live TV plan required. Regional restrictions, blackouts and additional terms apply.",
            link: "See Detials",
            bckgrd: "loginLib__bigEvents"
        }
    ]
```

1. I am mapping through the above array but it returns the three(3) objects at the sametime. How do i make it to return one object at time?

```
 return (
    <div className='loginLib'>
        <div className='loginLin__container'>
        {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
        <div defaultChecked={!(!!index)} className={`loginLib__spotlight ${active===tab.id? tab.bckgrd : "loginLib__spotlight--inactive"}`}>
            <div className='loginLib__newsOuter'>
                <div className='loginLib__newsInner'>
```

2. I have this three(3) buttons linked to each the three objects above, with onClick functionality and it works, but I dont want it in three(3) containers, rather, I want it in one container like a slide show.

```
                    <div className='loginLib__buttons'>
                        {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
                            <button><span
                            key={tab.name}
                            defaultChecked={!(!!index)}
                            value={tab.id}
                            type="radio"
                            onClick={() => {setActive(tab.id)}}
                            className={`${active===tab.id? "loginLib__button--active" : "loginLib__button"}`}
                            >{tab.name}</span>
                            <div onClick={() => {setActive(tab.id)}} className={`${ active===tab.id?'loginLib__activebar' : 'loginLib__activebar--inactive'}`}></div>
                            </button>
                        ))}
                        
                    </div>

                    <div className='loginLib__contents'>
                        <div className={`${active===tab.id?'loginLib__contentsContainer' : 'loginLib__contentContainer--inactive'}`}>
                            <div className='loginLib__contentsHeadline'>
                                <span>{tab.name}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className='loginLib__contentsSubHead'>
                                <span>{tab.subHeadline}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div className='loginLib__img'>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt='logo' src={tab.image1} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt='logo' src={tab.image2} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt='logo' src={tab.image3} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt='logo' src={tab.image4} />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div className='loginLib__text'>
                                <p>
                                    {tab.text} <a href='#'>{tab.link}</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

 </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div> 
        ))}

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginLib
```

3. How do i make the first button active on default??. If i should set the --inactive className to display = none. It works perfectly, only the --active className displays on the screen in one container, but if i refresh the page everything disappears, because none of the buttons are active on default.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're mapping each element in the array into the `<button><span>` elements. `Array.prototype.map` returns a new array of the same length. That means that you're returning 3 buttons by mapping over it.
2. With the map, it simply loops over each item, in this case, a single object.
3. `defaultChecked={index === 0}`

Comment: 3. For some reason, defaultChecked={index === 0} doesn't work for me.

Comment: I don't understand the rest of your answers to be honest. That's 1 & 2